# Apply XamDataGrid's FieldLayout to multiple dynamic Grids

Tags: c#, wpf, infragistics, xamdatagrid

I would like to be able to apply a single FieldLayout to multiple grids, which are dynamically created at run-time.

In my application, I use a search bar to type in a Type name, and when a Type is found a grid will render displaying all instances of that type on the server. The user should then be able to search for a different Type and thus replace the grid with a new one.

I am setting AutoGenerateFields in the FieldLayoutSettings to true since I do not know about the types I will be displaying until run time and the fields will differ across types. I do know, however, that they will share some fields that I do not wish to display on the grid (as they all extend the same abstract class). Therefore I am using a FieldLayout as follows:

```
    <igDP:XamDataGrid x:Name="MyGrid" DataSource="{Binding Items}" >
        <igDP:XamDataGrid.FieldLayoutSettings>
            <igDP:FieldLayoutSettings AutoGenerateFields="True"/>
        </igDP:XamDataGrid.FieldLayoutSettings>
        <igDP:XamDataGrid.FieldLayouts>
            <igDP:FieldLayout IsDefault="True">
                <igDP:Field Name="PropertyToNotDisplay" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                <igDP:Field Name="AnotherPropertyToNotDisplay" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
            </igDP:FieldLayout>
        </igDP:XamDataGrid.FieldLayouts>
    </igDP:XamDataGrid>
```

When I type in my first Type name and render the grid this FieldLayout is used as expected; all is well. However, the next time I type in a type name and render the grid, no FieldLayout is applied at all - everything is displayed including the fields I wish to hide. I have tried forcing the grid to use the FieldLayout by handling the grid's AssigningFieldLayoutToItem event in the code-behind as follows:

```
    private void MyGrid_OnAssigningFieldLayoutToItem(object sender, AssigningFieldLayoutToItemEventArgs e)
    {
        e.FieldLayout = MyGrid.FieldLayouts[0];
    }
```

And whilst this does apply the layout, it doesn't change the fields on the grid.

To illustrate what happens: If Type A has Fields 1, 2, 3 and Type B has fields 2, 3, 4 - when Type B is displayed it will display a grid of all Type B's instances, but with Type A's fields - which of course does not make sense and some data is missing. We end up with a grid with the fields 1, 2, 3 and all of the cells from the '1' column are empty.

It appears therefore that when a grid is created and the fieldlayout applied, the FieldLayout becomes coupled to the Fields it displays.

I have also tried adding the FieldLayout I require as a resource for my UserControl, setting `x:Shared="False"`so that it can be reused, and adding it in the code-behind like so:

```
    MyGrid.FieldLayouts.Add(this.Resources["FieldLayout"] as FieldLayout);
```

This essentially leaves me with the same behaviour as the original problem - the layout applies to the first grid and then is no longer used for subsequent grids. A combination of the above two solutions leaves me with the above issue of the Grid displaying the incorrect fields.

I would just like the same rules in the existing FieldLayout to be applied to every grid that is rendered. Any help would be much appreciated!

I'm attempting to follow an MVVM pattern so ideally would like to keep my code-behind clean, but if a solution requires a bit of code-behind I am of course willing to try (as I have already.)

Thanks!

**tl;dr** I swap out and render new grids at run-time, and need to apply the same FieldLayout to all of them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Infragistics support got back to me. As suspected, the FieldLayout becomes associated with the type it is bound to on creation, so it can't be reused in such a way. Instead of creating the FieldLayout in the xaml and attempting to reuse it, one potential solution is to get rid of the FieldLayout from the xaml and handle the `FieldLayoutInitialized` event on the xamDataGrid and hide the properties that way:

```
private void MyGrid_FieldLayoutInitialized(object sender, Infragistics.Windows.DataPresenter.Events.FieldLayoutInitializedEventArgs e) 
{
    var fld = e.FieldLayout.Fields.FirstOrDefault(f => f.Name.Equals("PropertiesToOldValues"));
    if (fld != null) fld.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    fld = e.FieldLayout.Fields.FirstOrDefault(f => f.Name.Equals("MagnetoProperty"));
    if (fld != null) fld.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
}
```

More overhead, but a new FieldLayout needs to be created with each new grid anyway.